# NetSuite dialog box with text field input (SuiteScript 2.0)

Tags: netsuite

Using SuiteScript 2.0, it looks like you can create alert/confirmation boxes using their UI framework (using N/ur/dialog module). Does anyone know if there's a way using the SuiteScript API to include a text input field (which the user can type into) on an alert or confirmation box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not officially supported, but seeing that N/ui/dialog is basically a wrapper function on Ext.js, you can use the following to create a NS styled input box:

```js
Ext.Msg.prompt('Title', 'Message', function(btn, text) {
    if (btn == 'ok') {
        alert('you said ' + text);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great tip, I'll give it a try. Interesting to see they're still using Ext.js v3.3.1 (released 6 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

Use clientscript to add this function to the button:

```
function promptForInput(){
    var theResponse = prompt('Type now');
    alert('User typed '  + theResponse);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something other than the vanilla js prompt box (NS styled), but I guess that's a quick and easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

Now there's a better way: Use the [NetSuite Input Dialog](https://netsuite-insights.com/2020/11/netsuite-input-dialog/) module which I recently released. Cheers.